# Is a Logging Facility similar to types of Windows Logs?

Tags: linux, logging

I'm learning about Linux (Debian/CentOS) for my Jr. System Administrator position. In my current module, it's going over Logging, and Logging facilities to be exact. I'm trying to get a grasp on what exactly the logging facilities are. Would you say that you could compare them to the types (Application, Security, Setup, System, Forwarded Events) within the Windows operating system? Sorry for the n00b question, just trying to get a better understanding of things.

Comment: Syslog is not the same as Windows events.  Trying to treat them as being the same will probably confuse you more, then if you just treat them as two separate things that have a somewhat similar purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The logging facility is an identification of a syslog packet that allows a syslog deamon to send the syslog message to the correct log file

The file syslog.conf on a unix server designates which log files syslog messages with a certain facility are sent.

read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Facility_levels